# Session in codeigniter model View Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

When I login success then redirect to the  home page.

After I  set session  in login and view page, when I refresh that same page then it is redirect in to the  login page, whats the reason for that and would you please provide solution for this problem?

**Controller**

```
public function login() {

    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

    $result = $this->search_model->login($email, $password);

    if($result !='') {

        $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $email);
        $seid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    }

    if ($seid=='') {

        //echo ($seid);

        $this->index();

    } else {

        $this->view();

    }

} 


public function view() {

    $seid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $data['result']=$this->search_model->getall($seid);
    $this->load->view('pagination_view',$data);

}
```

**Model**

```
function login($email, $password) {   
    $this->db->where("email", $email);
    $this->db->where("password", $password);
    $query=$this->db->get("tbl_reg");

    return $query->result_array();    
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
if(!$this->session->userdata('user_id'))
{
    redirect(base_url().'search/login');
}
else
{
}
?>
```

Comment: what errors are you getting? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: i did not  get any  error  bt  when i refresh   the   home page  it is redirect in to the  login page,

Answer (score 0):

Two problems, the first architectural the second likely causing your problem. The first is you should not be redirecting in a view. This should be in the controller that loads your home page (or other pages). You shouldn't even get to the view if you don't belong there.

The second problem is if($result!=''). This won't work. $result is an array. Use if(!empty($result)) or if(count($result)!==0) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

On your pagination_view I would not use redirect instead place that on controller function

```
public function view() {

if ($this->session->userdata('user_id') == FALSE) {

    redirect(base_url().'search/login');

} else {

    $data['result'] = $this->search_model->getall($seid);

    $this->load->view('pagination_view',$data);

}

}
```